# Why temporary questions are tolerated

Tags: support

The question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974170) is welcomed despite `it is is just a dump from my program for you to debug`. It worth only for a single person for a short period of time. Others cannot benefit from it and is not a good quality certainly. Am I missing the whole concept of what the `practical question` is?

Comment: It has a score of 0, in what way is it welcomed?

Comment: @RobertLongson It had score of 1 before I voted. Did I do a wrong thing?

Comment: No, downvoting is the appropriate way of marking a question as "unwelcome."

Comment: Not at all, your votes are your own to disperse as you see fit provided you target posts and not users.

Comment: Did you vote because you disagreed with the upvote or because the question wasn't clear/showed researched/useful? if its the former then you voted for the wrong reason. How do you know its only useful to this one person?

Comment: @Sayse I could not stand that bad question is welcomed. But I decided to make sure asking here anyway. Obviously, the sockets are fine because they are used for more than decade and nobody noticed the bidirection issue. If you want the Q to be helpful for others you concentrate on the data transfer demo, not on the file parsing. If you present us more details, you should tell that if I simply send the data, it works. If I add this line then it fails to deliver. That what `minimal demo` is. Is it hard to understand or I am missing something?

Comment: It's just a bad question for multiple reasons. #1, for me, is that it's some network/protocol problem that is sure to be environment-specific and the OP has done approximately zero useful debugging/wiresharking, just dumped it with some wooly concern about 'synchronization' without any protocol details.  Hopeless:(

Comment: 'I'm doing right now the debugging, if I have already found the reason of the problem I will not waste time to others to debugging it' - so considerate, post first, debug after:(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a question is not "tolerated", just ignored.  A title with "not working" is a pretty good way to discourage anybody from looking at it and voting on the question.

It is most certainly not "welcomed" either, of course not.  That upvote it got is pretty likely to be fake, cast with a sock puppet account.  The user's reputation page shows two previous vote corrections, the usual hint that he doesn't think too much about corrupting the system in his favor.  Happens a lot, users do most anything they can think of to draw attention and SE does little to slow them down.

Nothing that can ever be proven, the system is also strongly designed to make sure that nobody can ever be sure.  Best way is to flag the question for moderator attention, they can see more, Brad will sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason this question wasn't heavily downvoted and deleted/closed before was that not enough people saw it to make that happen. Now that more people have seen it, surprise surprise, it got deleted right away by the author, presumably in response to the DVs and close votes garnered since.

In the torrent of bad questions, a few slip through the cracks sometimes.

If you want to help with quality control, downvote bad questions and flag/vote to close where applicable.

Comment: Just FYI, it was not the meta mafia that deleted the question this time. It only garnered 2 close votes since being raised on meta, and it was deleted by the original author (H. DJEMAI). In my opinion, this wasn't a question that deserved closure, just a downvote. I guess the fellow found out no one was going to debug his code for him and gave up.

Comment: @CodyGray I edited my answer a little to make that more clear.

Comment: @CodyGray This question should not exist in the long term anyway. It won't be needed to the author himself after some time. It probably not need to be closed right away. But what is the point for this question to exist once it was answered?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov there isn't. And when OP didn't delete it from himself, someone else would.